# Class retain counts

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, retaincount, retain-cycle

Plenty is posted here about avoiding retain cycles with blocks, but what about when using classes and class methods?  Say I have a class like this:

```
// MyClass.h

+ (void)doSomethingAsynch:(void (^)(void))block;
+ (void)doSomethingElse;
```

and callers would like to say this:

```
[MyClass doSomethingAsynch:^{
    [MyClass doSomethingElse];
}
```

Must the caller declare an unsafe_unretained copy of MyClass?  Or is a class like a singleton, which won't increase it's retain count?  Does it matter if we send a class's retain count to the moon since we want it to exist all the time anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[NSObject class] retainCount]` returns `NSUIntegerMax`, so, yes, classes are implemented as singletons and probably override `release` as a no-op.

**Addendum:**

In the [objc runtime implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm) of `NSObject` at line 1659 you find ...

```
+ (id)retain {
    return (id)self;
}
```

... which verifies that `[NSObject retain]` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, classes are never going to be deallocated by the system, so it hardly matters if you retain them repeatedly and never release them. My guess would be that `retain` on a class does nothing.

Comment: ok thanks. +1 here and +1/correct on @Nikolai b/c of the helpful empirical evidence on class retain counts.

Answer (score -1):

You are exposing those methods as static/class methods (the '+' at the front instead of a '-' for instance methods), so of course you never need to do `[[MyClass alloc] init]` for this particular class if you only want to use those methods. Since you're not using `alloc`, you don't have to worry about `retain` or `release`.

These days with ARC (Auto Reference Counting) you **mostly** don't have to worry about `retain` and `release` anyway, it adds all that at compile time for you.

EDIT: stressed **mostly**, as there are times when you still need worry about it, also added some clarity

Comment: I think somebody did a -1 here because you do need to worry sometimes about memory mgmt even under ARC.  Retain cycles in blocks is an example of that.

Comment: I've tried to add some clarity to my answer, in this case its the same as a static class with static methods in C#, based just on what is provided in the question.